# Sort Line Segments in Order of Connections

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a dictionary of Line ID's and their 2 corresponding Point X,Y coordinates.
The 2 points are not guaranteed to be in the order of start, end points.
And I need to sort the ID's in order of how they are connected,  into a list.

`d= { 34:((3,5), (2,5)), 82:((1,1), (1,2)), 2:((8,4), (3,5)), 13:((1,2), (2,5))}`

I'll have a startEdge and startPt   example:  `startEdge = 82  startPt = 1,1`

I'm thinking I need some kind of iterator, but  have not had much success. My project could have up to 200+ line segments, so I'm trying not to slow the script down.  Any help would be great

edit:  here is what I started to try so far... but not sure how to get this in a loop

```
def get_key(val, my_dict):
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if val in value[0]:
            currEdge = key
            currPt = value[0]
            nextPt = value[1]
        if val in value[1]:
            currEdge = key
            currPt = value[1]
            nextPt = value[0]
```

Some Clarification, Sometimes the startEdge will have a few other edges on the side I don't want the path to go, therefore I need to give it a direction, or a "startPoint"

[image: line image]

Comment: What would the desired result be for the sample data in your question?

Comment: list = [82, 13, 34, 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution.  I would be interested to see how it performs on a larger dictionary.

```
def create_path(start_edge, start_point, dic):
    lst=[]
    edge = start_edge
    tail = start_point

    while len(dic.keys()) > len(lst):
        head = next(filter(lambda x: x != tail, dic[edge]))
        for e, points in dic.items():
            if head in points and e not in lst:
                lst.append(e)
                edge = e
                tail = head
    return lst

d= { 34:((3,5), (2,5)), 82:((1,1), (1,2)), 2:((8,4), (3,5)), 13:((1,2), (2,5))}
print(create_path(82, (1,1),d))

#output: [82, 13, 34, 2]
```

For Python 2.7, simply replace the lambda expression with this block of code to find the head:

```
    if tail == dic[edge][0]:
        head = dic[edge][1]
    else:
        head = dic[edge][0]
```

Comment: thanks! This looks like what I was attempting to do.   I forgot to mention i have to use Python 2.7   is that why I'm getting this error when I run that code?   TypeError: tuple object is not an iterator

Comment: Yeah, just tried it in Python 3.8 and it worked.... So Now I just have to figure out how to get it to work in Python 2.7

Comment: @MattClat. No problem. For Python 2.7, you can replace the lambda expression with simpler code.  See my amended solution.

Comment: awesome! Looks like with ~180 line segments, it took  0.0031039 seconds.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I need this solution in javascript , please help me